# Максимальный лимит одновременных подключений у TcpClient

Tags: c#, .net

1) Какой максимальный лимит одновременных подключений у TcpClient на Windows Server 2012r2 x64?

2) Каким образом возможно увеличить этот лимит (какие параметры реестра или опции клиента есть для этого)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Лимит исходящих соединений - 64k. Каждое исходящее соединение занимает один порт. Номер порта - 16-битное целое число.

Входящих - жесткого лимита нет, но, [по слухам](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dca7e775-b6c8-4b24-b75b-5799d8091836/does-server-20032008-have-tcp-connection-limits-like-xp-and-vista?forum=servercorefordevelopers), есть какой-то захардкоженный лимит в Windows Server Web и Windows Server Foundation.

В Standard/Enterprise/Datacenter явного лимита по умолчанию нет. Точнее, он есть, но его значение по умолчанию огромное. Задается в реестре в

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters]
TcpNumConnections = 0x00fffffe (Default = 16,777,214)
```